# Fetch Data from MySQL based on specific set of dates

Tags: mysql

i want to calculate the sum of the money i spent on the based on two specific dates, i have tried doing this using several queires but none of them seem to work. Below are the table and the query respectively,

```
     Product_ID----ProductName------price------OrderDate
    ---  1  --------  Chair -------- 7 ------ 2015-01-05
    ---  2  --------  Lamp --------- 14 ----- 2015-01-16
    ---  3  --------  Table -------- 9 ------ 2015-02-25

SELECT SUM(price) AS TotalPrice FROM orders
HAVING OrderDate >='2015-01-05' AND <= '2015-01-16'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS TotalPrice 
FROM orders
WHERE OrderDate >= '2015-01-05' AND OrderDate <= '2015-01-16'
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS TotalPrice 
FROM orders
WHERE OrderDate between '2015-01-05' AND '2015-01-16'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
HAVING OrderDate >='2015-01-05' AND <= '2015-01-16'
```

To

```
WHERE OrderDate >='2015-01-05' OrderDate AND <= '2015-01-16'
```

Comment: `having` is actually rather for the use of `group by`